# Is it possible to extend an object "into" a function?

Tags: javascript

I've always found it interesting that in JavaScript you can actually extend functions into objects:

```
var order = function(x, y) {
  return x < y ? [x, y] : [y, x];
};

order.backwards = function(x, y) {
  return order(x, y).reverse();
};
```

I won't claim there is much reason to do the above (but then again, why not?); my question is simply whether it's possible to do the opposite. That is, could I have something like:

```
var order = {
    backwards: function(x, y) {
        return order(x, y).reverse();
    }
};

// Obviously, this is not real; I'm just wondering if there's any way
// to accomplish the same thing.
addFunctionBehavior(order, function(x, y) {
    return x < y ? [x, y] : [y, x];
};
```

Comment: *"in JavaScript you can actually extend functions into objects"*: That's because functions **are** objects. But you cannot make an object a function afaik.

Comment: @FelixKling: Fair enough. But that doesn't invalidate my question, does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. What you can do is take an object and return a function.

Remember functions are objects, except they inherit from `Function.prototype` instead of `Object.prototype`

They also have an internal `[[Call]]` property that is invoked when they are invoked. you can't extend an object and give it a `[[Call]]` property.

However you would be able to do something very similar using [ES6 proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) (which are non-standard and have mediocre browser support).

Answer (score 0):

If you supply a name for the property you could do:

```
addFunctionBehavior(order, 'reverse', function(x, y) {
    return x < y ? [x, y] : [y, x];
};
```

given:

```
function addFunctionBehavior(o, name, fn) {
  o[name] = fn;
}
```

But I don't know why I'd want to do that instead of:

```
order.reverse = function (x,y) { ... }
```